# VB program to calculate grades

Tags: vb.net

So I am working on a program that will ask for the number of assignments, say 20, then run through a loop that many times asking for the total points earned on each assignment as well as the total points possible to get the final grade. For example if the user put in 2 assignments with assignment 1 earning 48 points out of 50 and assignment 2 earning 35 points out of 40 the program would display the grade as 92.

So far here is what I have:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim amountAssignments As Integer
        Dim pointsEarned As Integer = 0
        Dim pointsEarnedTotal As Integer = 0
        Dim pointsPossible As Integer = 0
        Dim pointsPossibleTotal As Integer = 0
        Dim Assignment As Integer = 1

        Integer.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, amountAssignments)

        Do Until Assignment > amountAssignments
            txtAmount.Text = String.Empty
            lblAmount.Text = "Enter Points Given on Assignment " & Assignment & ":"
            Integer.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, pointsEarned)
            pointsEarnedTotal = pointsEarnedTotal + pointsEarned
            lblAmount.Text = "Enter Points Possible on Assignment " & Assignment & ":"
            Integer.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, pointsPossible)
            pointsPossibleTotal = pointsPossibleTotal + pointsPossible
            Assignment = Assignment + 1
        Loop

        lblAmount.Text = "Enter the amount of Assignments: "
        lblGrade.Text = (pointsEarnedTotal / pointsPossibleTotal)

    End Sub
End Class
```

syntax is correct but when the program is run and the number of assignments put in and calculate entered the program displays the grade as NaN with no other input requested.

Could use another set of eye(s) to look over this and tell me where i screwed up logically.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? (Set a breakpoint at the start of your loop, and then run your app. Step through the code, watching what it does and what happens with your variables.) The debugger can be a very useful tool, so you should learn to use it sooner than later.

Comment: Definitely use the debugger - looking at the code I have a hunch it's not doing what you expect it to do.  Stepping through the code you will see exactly what's it doing, and where it's going off course from what you intended.

Comment: So after taking a step away and coming back it kind of hit me before even reading this, "what if the program isn't working because its not asking for the input?" Fairly certain that is what is causing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

This program seems to not have some sort of user intervention when the loop starts. What I would do is surely have the user enter the amount of assignments on the textbox and then from there would ask the user to enter marks from an input box separated by a slash e.g I enter 45/50 so after input the program finds the index of "/",all characters before the '/' are the `pointsEarned` and can be added to the `pointsEarnedTotal` while all the characters after the '/' are placed in the `pointsPossible` and added to the `pointsPossibleTotal`
Try this and tell me how it goes...give me points if it works
` Private Sub butGetMarks_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butGetMarks.Click
        Dim assignments As Integer = 0
        Dim totalAssignments As Integer
        Integer.TryParse(txtAssignments.Text, totalAssignments)

```
    Dim pointsEarned As Double = 0
    Dim pointsEarnedTotal As Double = 0

    Dim possibleEarned As Double = 0
    Dim possibleEarnedTotal As Double = 0
    Dim temp As String

    For i As Integer = 1 To totalAssignments
        temp = InputBox("Enter marks per assignment separated by /")
        Dim i1 As Integer
        i1 = temp.IndexOf("/") 'read index of /
        pointsEarned = temp.Substring(0, i1) 'read from start until / character
        possibleEarned = temp.Substring(i1 + 1) 'read from after / character onwards
        'add to totals
        possibleEarnedTotal += possibleEarned
        pointsEarnedTotal += pointsEarned
    Next i
    MessageBox.Show(pointsEarnedTotal & "/" & possibleEarnedTotal)
End Sub`
```

Comment: That does work I believe, its similar to what I finally came up with after everyone here suggested I use the debug tool. I would give you points but I don't have 15 rep yet. Sorry...

Comment: darn...i really need 50 points!! When u do get enough rep me up plz. Do try it and letme know whatsup so I feel good about my programming skills :D